# Scope of `define macros

Tags: verilog, system-verilog, hdl, system-verilog-assertions

This question is regarding system verilog macros.
I have a top-module, sub-module and a sub-sub module. sub-sub module instantiated in sub-module instantiated in top module.

If I define a macro `` `define abc ``  in the sub module, will the code written inside `` `ifndef abc `` gets compiled in the top module/sub-sub module

Answer (score 5):

The scope of `` `define `` macros and most other compiler directives is a *compilation unit*. A compilation unit is a stream of source text that a compiler parses. A macro gets defined at the point it appears in the compilation unit and is visible from that point onward.

The scopes defined by modules and other namespaces are irrelevant because macros are pre-processed before any Verilog or SystemVerilog syntax gets recognized. This means you can never have instance specific control over macro definitions.

There is a sight difference between how Verilog and SystemVerilog define a compilation unit.

In Verilog, each compilation unit is a compilation step, or one invocation of a tool that compiles your source code. Some tools only have one compilation step, requiring you to compile all your source code in one step. Other tools (e.g. Modelsim), allow you to compile your code in separate steps. A `` `define `` macro in one compilation step is not visible any other compilation steps unless you re-define it.

SystemVerilog adds the ability to treat each file on the compilers command line as a separate compilation unit. This was needed because SystemVerilog allows you to define things like typedefs and functions outside of a module. Keeping each file a separate compilation unit prevents naming collisions. (This compilation unit behavior is the same in C/C++).

Because of the way people mix legacy Verilog code with SystemVerilog, some tools allow you to choose the Verilog or SystemVerilog behavior of a compilation unit.

Answer (score 3):

Unless you are using `+define+...` in your compilation command, the `define` macro will take effect depending on the compilation order. Once it is compiled, it will be taken by any subsequent line of codes or files until corresponding `undef` is met.

Let say in your case, the compilation order is: `subsub.v`, `sub.v`, `top.v` (as per your modules name).

Assuming the `define abc` is on the first line of `sub.v`, this `abc` is effective in any subsequent line of `sub.v` as well as the remaining file which in this case is `top.v`, but not `subsub.v`.

So to answer your question, any codes within `ifndef abc` in `top.v` will NOT get compiled. On the other hand, the `ifndef abc` in `subsub.v` will get compiled.

[Example here](https://www.edaplayground.com/x/4UXg#_=_)